# In Python, how do you edit the values in a dictionary based on the frequency of its key?

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm creating a program that reads through a .txt file of names (lastname,firstname), one per line, and creates a dictionary that shows the number of times a specific first name repeats.

I've gotten the follow code so far but can't seem to accurately count the number of times a first name repeats. I think the problem is that my variable "value" doesn't correspond to the actual value in the key value pair. How can I fix that?

```
file = open('names.txt')

dict = {}
value = 1

for line in file:
    listOfNames = line.split(",")
    firstName = listOfNames[1]

    if dict.has_key(firstName):
        value += 1
    else: 
        dict[firstName] = value

file.close()
```

Comment: Sidenote:  The variable names *file* and *dict* shadow builtins of the same name.  Consider using different variable names.

Answer (score 6):

You may be interested in the [collections.Counter](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html) - which is a special dictionary for exactly this kind of task.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you want something like:

```
if dict.has_key(firstName):
    dict[firstName] += 1
else:
    dict[firstName] = 1
```

Also, I would *strongly* recommend you choose a name other than `dict`, such as `names`. The reason is that `dict` is the name of the standard Python dictionary type (just like you usually don't want to create Python variables called `str`, `int`, or `list`).

There are other solutions such as using [`collections.defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) that will be more succinct.

Comment: Excellent point on the "don't use 'dict' as a variable name". I second that comment.

Comment: Its recommended to use the `in` operator to test the presence of a key in a dictionary vs. the `.has_key()` method because it's a more highly optimized operation (no method lookup), but the concept remains the same.

Comment: The order of recommendations start with *dict.get* and then with *collections.Counter*, and only then a possible mention of *collections.defaultdict*.  The *get* recommendation is essential because a person should know all their fundament dict methods before branching out to learn new types.  *Counter* has precedence over *defaultdict* because it is easier to use (i.e. doesn't require knowledge of factory functions or the knowledge that *int* with no arguments returns zero) and because it was specifically designed for this use case.

Answer (score 2):

You can replace the if-block with:

```
dict[firstname] = dict.get(firstname, 0) + 1
```

Alternatively, you can use [collections.Counter](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) instead of a dict.  That simplifies to counting code to just:

```
c[firstname] += 1
```

where *c* is a *Counter* instance.

Answer (score 2):

Use a [defaultdict](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#defaultdict-objects) like this:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(int)
for name in open('names.txt'):
  _, first_name = name.split(",")
  d[first_name] += 1
```

You may want to normalize your names by stripping whitespace and capitalization.

Comment: Counter is preferred over collections.defaultdict for this use case.

Comment: +1: defaultdict is preferred over if statements shown in other answers.

Answer (score 2):

As @Aurora mentions, Counter is perfect for this.

```
>>> names = ['foo bar', 'foo baz', 'foo car', 'doo bar', 'doo baz', 'boo paz']
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter(name.split()[1] for name in names)
Counter({'baz': 2, 'bar': 2, 'paz': 1, 'car': 1})
```

Answer (score 2):

```
with open('names.txt') as f:
    firstNames = [line.split(',')[0] for line in f]

print collections.Counter(firstNames)
```

Comment: addendum: If you go for last names eventually, be aware that you may need to `.strip()` newline characters unless you do `.read().splitlines()`.

Comment: +1 for using Counter's constructor to automatically loop over this list of names.  You could also roll it all into one line with a genexp: ``print Counter(line.rstrip().partition(',')[1] for line in f)``